# VB6 MsgBox not working with ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb6

i am using vb6 application dll in my web application. in the vb6 application there are many Msgbox alerts are available. when i debug my web application i got the alerts from the dll.
when i configure it in the iis and browse no msgbox alerts are coming.where is the issue?

Comment: The issue is that you have MsgBox alerts in your DLL. They should never have been there to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to display message boxes on the server for debugging purposes, here is a link that describes how to do that:
[how to enable message box in IIS server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15941811/how-to-enable-message-box-in-iis-server)

It also explains why this is a bad idea. :)